# Django Rest Framework i18n works on GET but doesn't works on POST

Tags: django, python-2.7, internationalization, django-rest-framework

I have API in my project and need to make some data in response translatable.

So I have model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    NEW = 'new'
    CONFIRMED = 'confirmed'
    USED = 'used'
    CANCELED = 'canceled'

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (NEW, _('New')),
        (CONFIRMED, _('Confirmed')),
        (USED, _('Used')),
        (CANCELED, _('Canceled')),
    )

    service_subscription = models.ForeignKey(ServiceSubscription)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    ticket_order = models.ForeignKey(TicketOrder)
    begin_stamp = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=NEW)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=36, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=timezone.now)
    processed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
```

Serializer for that case:

```
class TicketViewSetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ('begin_stamp', 'status', 'changed')

    def get_status(self, obj):
        return obj.get_status_display()
```

And I have viewset where I call this:

```
class TicketViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketViewSetSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsCorpMember)

    @list_route(methods=['get', 'post'], url_path='check/(?P<event_schedule_pk>[0-9]+)')
    def check_ticket(self, request, event_schedule_pk, *args, **kwargs):

        event_schedule = get_object_or_404(EventSchedule, pk=event_schedule_pk)

        data = {}
        status = 200

        if request.method == "POST":
            # get ticket code
            code = request.data.get('code')
            try:
                ticket = self.queryset.select_for_update().filter(
                    code=code, begin_stamp=event_schedule.start, service_subscription__data__jcontains={'id': event_schedule.event_id})[0]
            except IndexError:
                return HttpResponseNotFound(ugettext('Code invalid or ticket is not for this event'))

            if ticket.status == 'confirmed':
                ticket.status = 'used'
                ticket.processed_by = request.user
                ticket.save()

            else:
                status_msg = {
                    'new': ugettext('Need to be paid firstly'),
                    'used': ugettext(u'Already used'),
                    'canceled': ugettext('Ticket is canceled')
                }
                data['message'] = status_msg.get(ticket.status)
                status = 400

            ticket_serializer = TicketViewSetSerializer(ticket)
            data['ticket'] = ticket_serializer.data

        event_schedule_serializer = EventScheduleCorpSerializer(event_schedule)
        data['event_schedule'] = event_schedule_serializer.data

        return Response(data, status=status)
```

and in urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'ticket', views.TicketViewSet)
```

I need to get ticket status translated according to user language from headers. When I call this viewset simply on GET(/ticket/) I get status translated, but when call on POST, I get data in default language. 
(I have from django.middleware.locale import LocaleMiddleware in my middleware classes)

So I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple. I've missed one important setting. I just need to add my locales folder to

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    ---------some existing folders-------------,
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ui/Api/locale'), # my folder I missed
)
```

and everything works fine now.